# Is [smart-home] too broad?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) tag is by far the biggest on the site, with 62 questions (about 19% of all questions) tagged with it.

However, as pointed out by dsample in [this answer](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/268/12), it's quite a broad tag. As far as I can tell, it just says "this question is about IoT in a home environment", so it doesn't really convey a lot of information.

It also doesn't match up with any of the tags used on other Stack Exchange sites:

- [[iot] on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iot)
- [[home-automation] on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home-automation)
- [[iot] on Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iot)
- [[home-automation] on Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-automation)

<sup>Note: [iot](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iot) is not valid for this site, and is blacklisted because the *whole site* is about IoT.</sup>

Could we improve this tag to make it more useful? We could consider:

- synonymising [home-automation](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-automation) with [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) and then leave it as it is.
- burninating [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) and using more specific tags
- narrowing down [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) to be used for a specific purpose rather than just anything in a home
- doing nothing at all.

What do you think? Share your views on the tag below, and if you have any good ideas about how we can improve [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) (if it *does* need improving), feel free to suggest those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> synonymising [home-automation](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-automation) with [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) and
>
> narrowing down [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home)

Smart-home should (here) be more about the *home*, not the appliances. I think we have a different focus compared with the other sites, we have some other big areas of interest (particularly if more developers start to come this way).

However, it may be useful for some users to be able to follow smart-home, rather than a collection of other tags. I'm still on the side of removing the [smart-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-home) where there is a better tag, such as [lighting](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting), [smart-tv](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-tv), [smart-plugs](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-plugs), [digital-cameras](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-cameras) etc. Even then, we have a fair number of more general questions which are about the system context rather than individual elements.